# Listing the total sum of all possible sums in a set with constraints

Tags: java, math, recursion, probability, expectations

I am keen to find out the following:

Given a set with N elements, my friend and I are playing a game.I always make the first move.
We can only remove either the first or the last element with 50% chance each.We take alternate turns in the game.If only one element remains,we can remove it for sure.What is the expected sum that I can collect?

```
For example:N=2 {10,20} Possible sets that I can collect are {10},{20}.
So expected sum is 0.5*10+0.5*20=15.
```

My approach:

Since probability of getting a possible sum is equal in all cases,we only need to compute the sum of all possible sums and then multiply it by (0.5)^N/2.

I tried to use recursion to compute the required sum:

```
f(i,j)-computes the sum between i and j recursively
f(i,j)=2*a[i]+func(i,j-2)+func(i+1,j-1)+func(i+1,j-1)+func(i+2,j)+2*a[j]);
Initial call f(1,N)
```

But the approach doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Complete function is below:

```
class CandidateCode {
    static long v[][] = new long[1003][1003];

    public static long func(int a[], int i, int j) {
        if (i == j)
            return v[i][j] = a[i];
        if (v[i][j] != 0)
            return v[i][j];
        else {
            if (i > j - 2 && i + 1 > j - 1 && i + 2 > j)
                return (v[i][j] += 2 * a[i] + 2 * a[j]);
            else
                return (v[i][j] += 2 * a[i] + func(a, i, j - 2) + func(a, i + 1, j - 1) + func(a, i + 1, j - 1)
                        + func(a, i + 2, j) + 2 * a[j]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n;
        int a[] = { 0, 6, 4, 2, 8 };
        n = a.length - 1;
        System.out.println(func(a, 1, 4) / Math.pow(2, n / 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: N<=1000 and 1<=a[i]<=100

Comment: `We can only remove either the first or the last element with 50% probability` which means in each turn, you can get either first or last one (but always guarantee to get 1, just like flip a coin)  or you can choose and the chance you can get what you chose is 50 %?

Comment: we can choose either the first or the last element and that probability is 1/2..yes we are guaranteed to get one element at each turn @Pham Trung

Comment: Didn't get the game rules, but to solve problem mentioned in the title: get all the power sets of the numbers (there are existing algos for that), then for each combination check the precondition. If it holds, calculate the sum. That's all.

Comment: N=1000 how to use power sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by applying dynamic programming.

First, we have the state of the game is `(player ,start, end)` ,which indicates the current player, and the range of values that's available in the original set. At the beginning, we start at player 0 and `start` is 0, `end` is N - 1.

Denote that the first player is 0 and the second player is 1, we have the expected value of player 0:

```
 if(player == 0){
    double result = 0.5*( set[start] + f(1, start + 1,end) ) + 0.5*(set[end] + f(1,start, end - 1));
 }else{
     double result = 0.5*( f(0, start + 1,end) ) + 0.5*(f(0,start, end - 1));
 }
```

So for each state, we can store all calculated state in a `dp[player][start][end]` table, which reduce the time complexity to O(2*N*N) with N is number of value in set.

Pseudo code:

```
 double expectedValue(int player, int start, int end, int[]set){
       if(start == end)
          if(player == 0)
             return set[start];
          return 0;
       if(already calculated this state)
          return dp[player][start][end];
       double result= 0;
       if(player == 0){
          result = 0.5*( set[start] + f(1, start + 1,end) ) + 0.5*(set[end] + f(1,start, end - 1));
       }else{
          result = 0.5*( f(0, start + 1,end) ) + 0.5*(f(0,start, end - 1));
       }
       return dp[player][start][end] = result;
  }
```

Comment: could n't understand..can u plz elaborate?

Comment: @rajarshi369 In which part you don't understand?

Comment: transitions in the dp

Comment: @rajarshi369 we first start with a full set , so we can only take out the element at position 0 or position N - 1, so, the next state can only be (start + 1, end) or (start, end - 1) right? and the player take turn, so player 0 -> player 1 -> player 0...

Comment: @rajarshi369 and we only need to care about player 0, so only add into the result the value when player == 0, that's it!

Comment: @rajarshi369 correct :), glad you get it (Please accept this answer if it helps you)